# Enforce synchronicity in multi agent systems

Tags: scala, akka, agent

In an effort to learn both scala and akka I'm writing a Battleship game. I've not started actually writing any code yet, I'm merely thinking about how things would work.

I have agents for ships and player fleets, and messages such as "shot fired", "hit", "miss", "all ships killed". My first stumbling block is that when player 1 shoots it creates a burst of events, and player 2 must wait until all has settled before he can play his turn. How can I make sure of that ? I thought maybe I'd always send a reply no matter what, and then count that a sender receive exactly as many answers as messages sent. Maybe Battleship isn't the best candidate application for agents.

This also brings the question of making the difference between receiving no answer because the message was not processed yet, the agent didn't reply anything, or the agent died. But I'll save that one for later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things you might want to do here:

- Have the first actor receive replies to each of its messages and then send a *your turn* message to the second actor
- Send a message to the second actor indicating how many events in a given turn must be received

These are achievable as follows:

```
import akka.pattern._
(d1 ? m1) zip (d2 ? m2) pipeTo that
```

in the above example, `d1/2` are the destination actors, `m1/2` are the messages to be sent. The replies from these actors are zipped together (into a `Tuple2`) and forwarded on to the second actor (`that` in the example)

The second mechanism is a bit more involved; I've written similar things using `SyncPoints`. So, something like this:

```
case class SyncPoint(id: UUID, participants: ActorRef*)
object SyncPoint {
  def newFor(participants: ActorRef*) = SyncPoint(UUID.createRandomUUID, participants)
}
```

Then the creator of a message sends out a SyncPoint to the ultimate observer first

```
val sync = SyncPoint.newFor(d1, d2)
that ! sync
```

Now the ultimate receiver knows it is expecting a message on this `SyncPoint` for each participant.

```
d1 ! SyncPart(m1, sync)
d2 ! SyncPart(m2, sync)
```

Where

```
case class SyncPart(msg: Any, sync: SyncPoint)
```

The actors `d1` and `d2` will forward on to `that` when they have processed their part in the message.

```
case class SyncPartial(sync: SyncPoint, participant: ActorRef)
```

In this way, `that` knows it is expecting messages from a number of participants and can then track when these participants have performed their processing.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll go with the first approach since I don't known in advance how many event will be generated.